# В какой момент, при выполнении Vuex action, задачи на изменение добавляются в очередь тиков?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

При условии наличия множественных *commit* в теле *action*-а:

```
actions: {
    async action({ commit }) {
        commit('commit1');
        await sleep(2000);
        commit('commit2');
        await sleep(2000);
        commit('commit3');
    },
}
```

Гарантирует ли *action*, что *commit*-ы, внутри него, отработают **последовательной** пачкой и в рамках **одного** тика? Или же между задачами, инициированными 'commit1' и 'commit2', в очередь может добавиться 'some_other_commit_from_other_action'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть подробное описание [документации vuejs](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9). Если почитать на досуге, то многое становится ясно и все последующие вопросы отпадают сами, но даже если нет, вы всегда будете знать где взять информацию.

Итак если вкратце, то все изменения становятся в очередь. Любое изменение DOM осуществляется через очередь тиков. Если какой-то проперти изменился несколько раз, то он заменит предыдущий тик в своей очереди. Поэтому основываясь на документации можно сделать вывод, что все изменения, которые были порождены вызовами `commit` встанут в очередь и изменятся последовательно.

**UPD.**

Вы не поняли принцип работы реактивности. Изменение каждой проперти создает в очереди задачу на обновление DOM. Если по окончанию выполнения `action` были затронуты три разных проперти, то создадутся 3 задачи на обновление, которые отработают последовательно. 
**Vuex** - это просто плагин, который выступает в роли глобального сервиса по хранению данных. Он логирует каждое изменение store, одна мутация = одна запись в лог (вместе со всеми `state`), но никак не изменение трех разных мутаций сразу, т.к. они запустятся последовательно.

**UPD2**

У вас action с 3 commit внутри (грубо это породит 3 новых тика). Сам action это асинхронная приблуда, а commit  синхронная. Мы не знаем что они делают, но предположу, что изменяют разные объекты в `store`. Отработал `commit('commit1')` и тут же появилась задача в пуле тиков на обновление DOM. Она может успеть, а может и нет обновить DOM прежде чем запустится следующий `commit('commit2')`, который также следов встанет в очередь, потому что очередь работает асинхронно и добавление в очередь происходит автоматически. Ваши `sleep` не изменят ситуацию.

И да между 'commit1' и 'commit2' может оказаться другое изменение, повторяю потому что очередь асинхронна.

Comment: Смущает наличие прослойки в лице Vuex. Ведь, чисто технически, он может кешировать изменения, дожидаясь окончания выполнения как mutation, так и action.

Comment: @KanViner обновил свой ответ.

Comment: перефразировал вопрос, учтя ваш ответ

Comment: @KanViner один вызов `action` может породить множество тиков и не факт что между ним не встрянет что-то еще. Обновил.